# Input Date in Struts2

Tags: struts2

How to change the format of java.util.Date object in struts 2. What I have tested, Struts 2 accepts m/d/yy. Is it possible to change the format?

And also how to change the default message "Invalid field value for field date"?

date tag in struts2 can only be used in output.

Comment: It is a little confusing... By accepts you mean what is input? In that case the date format is expects is based on the users locale.  If you mean to format it on a JSP I would say that is a different issue although I wish there was one setting that would globally set the format, I don't think there is. mprabhat shows how to format on the JSP side.

Comment: yes. accept, i mean input. I want my user to input in different format if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass format to `s:date` tag

```
<s:date name="myDate" format="yyyy-MM-dd" />
```

To change the default error message, in your `validation.xml` you can add message parameter

```
   <field name="myDate">
        <field-validator type="date">
            <message key="errors.myDateRequired" />
        </field-validator>
    </field>
```

Then in your `ApplicationResources.properties` file you will provide value for `errors.myDateRequired`

Update: As per comment

`s:date` is only a read only tag which means cannot be used to accept input from user.

For enabling textField to accept date in different format, couple of approaches:

1. Use struts2-jQuery plugin, it has a very nice date picker which support different date timeformat, [showcase](http://www.weinfreund.de/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action), [DatePickerTag](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/DatePickerTag).
2. Custom javascript code to format user input.
3. Use jQuery (if allowed) and use jQuery datepicker

You can use custom converter to use text field for date, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750991/nosuchmethodexception-in-struts2/10751705#10751705)

Comment: <s:date/> tag will format the display. What I want is to allow user to input different format in a textfield.

Comment: so it's not possible to set in struts2 without client scripting? ok, thanks.

Comment: If you use jQuery plugin then it is very much possible, but you are correct that client scripting is done behind the scene

Comment: @JRGalia If you want Struts and text field, use CustomConverter, updated my post

Answer (score 0):

The date format Struts accepts depends on the user's locale. So for different locales you can have different date formats. This way you won't be able to support multiple date formats for the same locale but I don't see why you would need this anyway, it's only going to confuse your users. The only way to support different date formats for the same locale without javascript would be with a custom date converter as @mprabhat notes.

Answer (score 0):

You could see the official doc about this:

Define the format for every language y the resource bundle. For instance, an appropriate en_US format definition extension could look like this:

```
format.date = {0,date,MM/dd/yy}
```

In parallel, you could add the following to your de_DE bundle:

```
format.date = {0,date,dd.MM.yyyy}
```

http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/formatting-dates-and-numbers.html