# NoSuchMethodException in Struts2

Tags: struts2

I have textfield for birthDate. When a user enter invalid date, let say for example a String, error message successfully displayed as fielderror. But in my console, I got this error:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Profile.setBirthDate([Ljava.lang.String;)

Have I missed something that's why I encountered the error?

Answer (score 1):

In your Action class you dont have a method called `setBirthDate(String birthDate)`, add it your issue should be resolved.

Note check to see that you have placed all getter and setter in your action class for all properties.

I think in your JSP you have :

```
<s:textfield name="birthDate" />
```

Struts will try to map this to `setBirthDate(String string)`, since this method is missing in your action hence the `NoSuchMethodException`

Update:

To convert String to Date:

```
public class MyStringToDateConverter extends StrutsTypeConverter {
    public Object convertFromString(Map context, String[] values, Class toClass) {
       //Parse String to get a date object
    }

    public String convertToString(Map context, Object o) {
       // Get the string from object o
    }
 }
```

If you are using Annotation in your action class then add `@Conversion()` to your action

```
@Conversion()
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport{
    public Date myDate = null;

    @TypeConversion(converter="MyStringToDateConverter") //Fully qualified name so if this class is in mypackage then converter will be "myPackage.MyStringToDateConverter"
    public void setMyDate(Date date) { 
        this.myDate = date;
    }
}
```

If you dont want to use Annotation then you can look at the [official documentation](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/type-conversion.html) for example.

Comment: it's java.util.Date, not String.

Comment: s:textField will map to String and not date